# How to display a 5secend video before page load in html?

Tags: html, css, playback, pageload

I have a simple Html5 landing page and i want to show a 5secend video before the main page. it could be a popup or anything all i want is to display the video without any borders,playback buttons etc. and then load the main page.

Greetings! 
this is what i tried

```
<script>
  function openColorBox(){
    $.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%", href: "http://as2.asset.aparat.com/aparat-video/325cc0361862066dc06e8fb1fc7ec8a77684093-240p__39060.mp4"});
  }


  setTimeout(openColorBox, -5000);
  $.colorbox({ overlayClose: true });


</script>
```

Comment: We are not here to code for you. We're here to code with you. Show us what you tried and where you're stuck and then ask again.

Comment: sorry, done. added

Comment: You should really read up on how setTimeout works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple page which loads the video in bootstrap modal window. Hope this gives you a start!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        .modal-backdrop {
            background-color: #ccc;
        }

        .modal-backdrop.in {
            opacity: 0.2;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 style="text-align:center;">Hello</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
                <center><video id="myVideo" src="http://as2.asset.aparat.com/aparat-video/325cc0361862066dc06e8fb1fc7ec8a77684093-240p__39060.mp4" autoplay style="border-radius:5px;width:100%;"></video></center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
    <script>
    $("#myModal").modal()
    $(".container").hide();
    document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', closeModal, false);

    function closeModal() {
        $(".container").show();
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: it's a good start, thank you. i should now find how to disappear it after 5sec and load the mainpage content.